# Обнуление дескриптора сокета при передаче потоку через адрес структуры

Tags: c++, linux, многопоточность, сокеты

Есть структура, объявленная в глобальной области

```
struct s_login{ 
    int* newsock;
    int* count;
}
```

При инициализации ее дескриптором сокета полученным из accept()

```
if((t = accept(listener, (sockaddr*) &clnt_addr, &len)) < 0)...
```

и счетчиком i в порождающем процессе значения членов структуры сохраняется.
При передаче в новый поток

```
pthread_create(pthread, NULL, login, &slog);
```

в новом потоке при приведнии типа void* к s_login* значение count прежнее, а значение дескриптора сокета обнуляется.

```
void* login(void *arg)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    s_login *pslog = (s_login*) arg;
    cout << "Номер сокета: " << (*(pslog->newsock)) << endl;
    cout << "Счетчик: " << (*(pslog->count)) << endl;
    .....}
```

Почему, как исправить? Адреса хранятся в int.

Comment: Выбросьте глобальную структуру долой. И дизайн улучшите, и от проблемы наверняка избавитесь. Лучше всего создавать новую структуру на куче и передавать на нее указатель.

Comment: @gbg спасибо, действительно, когда структуру сделал через new, то все заработало. Но интересно почему так? Может, дело в разделении адресного пространства между родителем и потомком?

Comment: адресное пространство общее, а вот устроить гонки на кэшах или непонятки с оптимизатором - раз плюнуть.

Comment: @RomanMarkov Не вижу кода заполняющего структуру перед созданием потока, возможно там собака порылась, возможно если объявить переменные volatile, проблема так же исчезнет, но не навсегда, ибо так передавать параметры нельзя, что будет если будет два accept-a подряд, а порождаемые потоки стартанут с некоторой задержкой?

Comment: @Roman Markov Где находятся переменные, на которые указывают поля структуры? Какое значение дескриптора вернул `accept`?

Comment: Если Вы используете C++, то почему бы не работать с потоками при помощи [STL](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) ?

Comment: Зачем в структуре Вы храните указатели на int? Вы тем самым хотите сэкономить память или ускорить доступ к переменным? Так указателем на int будет по сути тот же int. Кроме как дополнительных граблей Вы ничего не выигрываете.

Comment: @dsnk вот код заполнения структуры
                `s_login*    pslog = new s_login;
                pslog->newsock = &newsockets[i];
                pslog->count = &i;`

Comment: &Konstantin Les я пробовал помещать обе переменные как в глобальную область так и внутри main(), результат всё равно один и тот же. accept() как обычно по первости возвращает 4, это значение видно через `cout <<  *pslog->newsock` в main, а в потоке то же самое показывает ноль. Но, что странно, счётчик показывает нормально и там и там `cout <<  *pslog->count`

Comment: @Max ZS всё верно, указатель на дескриптор сокета в структуре излишен, это остаток от моих попыток добиться его нормального значения в потоке.
Насчёт STL не знал, что там есть шаблоны для работы с потоками. Я знаю про контейнерные классы и работу с ними.